# Plano convex lens refraction angles formula

Tags: physics

I am designing an optical device with several plano-convex lenses. In order to determine several measurements I need to be able to calculate the resulting refracted angles in a diagram like this: (determine a2 if i know a1)

[lens diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMI4z.png)

However, with no formal education in optics, I'm having a hard time finding an applicable formula for this endeavour. Any help would be appreciated a ton!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).